# InfluxDB 2.0 getting stopped after putting the service in systemd

Tags: linux, influxdb

I have installed Influxdb 2.0 and it was working fine until I put influxd service in systemd.
Below is the content of influxdb.service

```
    [Unit]
    Description=InfluxDB 2.0 service file.
    Documentation=https://v2.docs.influxdata.com/v2.0/get-started/
    After=network-online.target

    [Service]
    User=influxdb
    Group=influxdb
    ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/influxd 
    Restart=on-failure

    [Install]
    WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in the user with which influxdb is getting started. I was using a dedicated user "influxdb" to start the service. The user was created using below command :

```
# useradd -rs /bin/false influxdb
```

Using `journalctl -u influxdb` and `influxd -h`, I found that influxdb creates a boltdb inside home directory of the user from which service has been ran. Since /home/influxdb doesn't exists I was getting the error.

Solution options:

- Change user in influxdb.service file to root.
- Create home for "influxdb" user using `mkhomedir_helper influxdb`
- Mention explicit location for boltDB using `--bolt-path` option